# How could I provide 2FA code to a ssh prompt?

Tags: ssh, google-2fa

I have set up ssh to work with 2FA, and it all works. So when I `ssh user@ip`, I'm being asked for a verification code: `(user@ip) Verification code:`

I would like to be able to be able to automatically have this code provided, so something like `echo 123456 | ssh user@ip` but that doesn't work, I'm still being asked for the verification code.

Any idea if that is possible and how?